# MySQL how to select records which value has image name

Tags: mysql, select

I have chat history table which has normal text & image names in message_text field and now I want to search records which has image in message_text. I tried with this query `SELECT * FROM em_chat_history WHERE message_text IN (jpg,jpeg,png)` but getting 0 records.

```
em_chat_history table:
id      user_id     username    message_text            room_id     created_at
46      188         XXXXX       XXXXX                   SW7gpNiHYd  2017-05-23 12:15:09
48      187         XXXXX       image1495530526.jpeg    SW7gpNiHYd  2017-05-23 12:10:42
49      188         XXXXX       XXXXX                   SW7gpNiHYd  2017-05-23 12:10:49
50      188         XXXXX       image1495530527.jpeg    SW7gpNiHYd  2017-05-23 12:10:49
53      191         XXXXX       XXXXX                   AQ7gpNiHYd  2017-05-23 12:15:09
54      187         XXXXX       XXXXX                   AQ7gpNiHYd  2017-05-23 12:16:18
```

Any Idea why I am getting 0 records.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LIKE` clause.

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM em_chat_history 
    WHERE message_text LIKE '%jpg' 
    OR message_text LIKE '%jpeg'
    OR message_text LIKE '%png'
```

Also if you need to search this terms that are in the middle of the string, you could use this query

```
SELECT * FROM em_chat_history 
    WHERE message_text LIKE '%jpg%' 
    OR message_text LIKE '%jpeg%'
    OR message_text LIKE '%png%'
```

Basically percent sign tells you from which side you allow wildcard.

Placing percent sign on the right means you look for a string starting with `jpg`, placing it on the left, means you're looking for string ending with `jpg`, and placing it on both sides you just want any string containing `jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM em_chat_history WHERE message_text LIKE '%jpg' OR message_text LIKE '%jpeg' OR  message_text LIKE '%png';
```

You should use LIKE and OR operator together. IN operator would check for exact matches.